# How can I add a layout to a string of content when using requestAction in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, layout

I'm building a CakePHP site where users can press a button to "save this newsletter as HTML". It seemed like a good idea to use a combination of `requestAction` and a media view to serve up the content to them, so that they get the exact same content as the live app. The only downside is that `requestAction` uses an empty layout, so there are no HTML headers or footers.

Is there an easy way, given a string which contains a body of HTML, to build a new string with the full page contents based upon a given layout?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an undocumented feature that if your `options` array has `0` as the value for the `bare` key, then the returned results will include the layout:

```
$newsletter_html = $this->requestAction(
                       array(
                           'controller' => 'Newsletters',
                           'action' => 'view'
                       ),
                       array(
                           'pass' => array($id),
                           'return',
                           'bare' => 0
                       )
                    );
```

Comment: Things may have changed since 2009, because in the latest version of Cake I had to make `'bare' => false`, but thanks for the tip!